# How to transition from HEX to gradient in CSS?

Tags: css, hex, css-transitions, radial-gradients

How can I create a background transition from HEX color to gradient and back?

My variable `--base` is just white and the transition between HEX and gradient doesn't work.

```css
:root {
  --app: radial-gradient( circle 753.6px at 10% 20%, rgba(248,167,221,1) 0%, rgba(230,192,254,1) 41%, rgba(169,217,243,1) 90% );
  --base: #FFFFFF; /* radial-gradient(#FFFFFF, #FFFFFF) */
}

body {
  background: #DDD;
}

div {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 300px;
  background: var(--base);
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
div:hover {
  background: var(--app);
}
```

```html
<div>test</div>
```

When i trying change **--base** to **radial-gradient(#FFFFFF, #FFFFFF)** so doesn't work too. Have anyone solution for this?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qLmtf21r/)

Comment: Not sure if I get your problem. You have white div, you hover over it and in changes the colour immediately. Do you have issues in fading in this colour or?

Comment: I want to apply a transition that doesn't work. The background changes immediately regardless of the transition value. I want smooth 1s transition from this white to gradient and back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a solution for you: https://jsfiddle.net/axgq60ro/4/
In order to create a transition between these two, you need to use the trick with z-index.
For further information check this article: https://keithjgrant.com/posts/2017/07/transitioning-gradients/
Have a nice day!

```
div:hover::before {
   opacity: 1;
}
```